# How to solve ploting problem with Qt and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a problem with plotting graph.
my code with the console works fine, but with Qt, the problem began.
I need to see a graph, then to choose, if it is good (to complete), or bad (to skip it), and go on.

in the console I used (input), with Qt, I used (QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question) and (input). with Qt, the graph shows in the background, and the question pops up, and I can't do nothing with the graph or see it until I answer the question in the message. and what I need is to answer the question after cheeking the graph.

```
def graphic_show(self):

        count_folder = 1
        count_file = 1
        res=''
        file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
        z = 0
        while z == 0:
     
            y = str(count_folder) # folder name
            y_2 = str(count_file) # file name
           #     for xj in range(1,32):
           #         print("I'm here...2")
            #xj = int(str(self.lineEdit_15.text()))
            source = Path(os.getcwd() + '/' + 'Data File' + '/' + y +'/' + y+ '5', y_2 + '_new'+'5'+'.txt')
            
            dest = Path(y_2 +'5'+'.txt') # точка 1
            
           # source = Path(os.getcwd() + '/' + 'Data File' + '/' + y +'/' + y+ str(self.lineEdit_15.text()), y_2 + '_new'+str(self.lineEdit_15.text())+'.txt')
           
           # dest = Path(y_2 +str(self.lineEdit_15.text())+'.txt') # точка 1

            with open(source,'r') as rs, open(dest,'w') as dst:
                dst.write(rs.read())        
            with open(dest , 'r' )as ff:
                x1 = ff.readlines()
                                      
                                                                    
                x1 = [float(i) for i in x1]
                                        

                x2 = x1[0:100]
                zero1 = statistics.mean(x2)

                peaks = find_peaks(x1, height=zero1+100,distance = 10)
                height = peaks[1]['peak_heights'] # list of the heights of the peaks
                peak_pos = peaks[0] # list of the peaks positions

                                            
                np.savetxt('индекс_пика.txt',peak_pos,fmt=['%d'])

                np.savetxt('пик.txt',height,fmt=['%.2f'])
                
                                  
                fig = plt.figure()
                ax = fig.subplots()
                ax.plot(x1)
                ax.scatter(peak_pos, height, color = 'r', s = 15, marker = 'D', label = 'max')
            
                ax.legend()
                ax.grid()
            
                plt.show()




                
            check = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,'Is it good?', ' is the file good?',
                                                   QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
                                                   QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No,
                                                   QtWidgets.QMessageBox.stop)
            if ckeck == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                count_folder = count_folder + 1
                count_file = count_file + 1     
                pass
            elif QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No:
                zero_cor = input(' enter the value to correct the zero!')
                zero1 = float(zero_cor)....
```

The same thing happens if I use the (input) instead of (QtMessage).

```
                plt.show()

                g = input('is the file good??')

                if g == 'y':
                    count_folder = count_folder + 1
                    count_file = count_file + 1
```